# mysql displaying all contains of the table

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to display the mysql table using php, i mean display the records with field names without specifying the row names.

example

### |id|name |address  |status | <--- this is the field in the mysql table

|1|name1 |address1 |status1| <-- this is the records

and more records...

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea:

1. Run `DESCRIBE tablename` and get field names/type
2. Run `SELECT * FROM tablename` and get records

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to display all records in the table?

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tabel")

the star means you will select all rows. change table to your table name..

Now all your table information is stored in $sql